# ActionBar.setTitle() having NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am trying to change the title of my Activity but I am getting this NullPointerException. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("SignUp");
}
```

I have tried setting setDisplayShowTitleEnabled() to true but still doesn't work.
I've tried other solutions from other similar questions but none seems to be helping.

Comment: check the AndroidManifest.xml of your app and make sure you are using a theme with has the ActionBar

Comment: post your style.xml file

Comment: Please post your styles and layout code here

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

Answer (score 1):

Your class extends from AppCompatActivity, so you have the option to use `setTitle()`